# Best way to continue stopped move (mv) by merging directories?

Tags: command-line, rename, file-copy

I have moved (mv) a pretty large directory on my NAS (Linux based), but had to interrupt the procedure. Not being a regular Linux user, I though I could just continue and merge the rest later in.

```
mv /oldisk/a /newdisk
```

Procedure is halfway done, so rest of `/oldisk/a` still exists, and `/newdisk/a` with the already copied files is already present. I have no idea which files have been already copied. BTW, under `/oldisk/a`, of course, are plenty of sub directories.

What would be the best way to move / merge the remaining files to `/newdisk/a` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`rsync --verbose --archive --dry-run /oldisk/a/ /newdisk/a/`

The `--dry-run` (or `-n`) will do a dry run, showing you what it would do without actually doing anything.

If it looks ok, run the rsync without the `-n` option.

This will be a copy, not a move, which isn't quite what you're doing, but is safer. The `--archive` (or `-a`) ensures all the ownership and timestamps metadata is preserved (which a regular copy would not).

Comment: Copy is OK, can always remove the old directory later.

Comment: You can use `--remove-source-files` to delete the files that have been successfully copied. Also, `-P` or `--progress` will show an estimate of how many more files there are to do.

Comment: so as an example of a move: `rsync --remove-source-files --recursive --times --crtimes 1/* 2/`

Comment: @deltab, --progress draws a new bar for each individual file, instead there is --info=progress2 for the whole tranfer.

Comment: Wow, that is pretty sad. Mv is definitely broken that it needs other tools to do what it should be able to do by itself. I just found this out, mv refuses to write into an existing directory, which is pretty pathetic. Time to replace this command with something more functional.

Comment: Not necessarily. The unix philosophy is precisely that each tool should do one simple thing, and you can combine them to do more complex things.

Comment: @把友情留在无盐 But remember to remove `--verbose` flag unlike me